# Null pointers why I get this output?

Tags: c, pointers

I newly try to learn pointers in C . so I use (null pointers) `int *pnumber = NULL;` but I don't get it why I get 17824320 in output.could you please explain ?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int main() {

        int number = 0;
        int *pnumber = NULL;
        number = 10;
        pnumber = &number;
        printf("%d \n", number);
        printf("%d \n", pnumber);

        return 0;

    }
```

**And the output is**

> 10
>
> 17824320 (I think memory address)

Comment: because you assign it at `pnumber = &number;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> pnumber = &number;
> ...
> printf("%d \n", pnumber);
> ```

The initial NULL values coming from `int *pnumber = NULL;` is modified by `pnumber = &number;` so you write the value of *pnumber* being the address of *number*

If you do `printf("%d \n", *pnumber);` that writes 10

Comment: Thanks for your help